# Firebase problems comes when i install pods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

XCode Version 13.3 (13E113)
cocoapods: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods.rb
pods:
Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :105, '9.0'
target 'b3st1lling' do
Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

Pods for b3st1ll1ng

target 'b3st1l11ngTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
Pods for testing
end

target 'b3st1llingUITests' do
Pods for testing
en

end

[photo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIqIC.png)